# What is data-dependency barrier: Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, dependencies, memory-barriers, smp

As question says it all I was looking for in depth explanation of **data-dependency barrier** in SMP especially with respect to Linux Kernel. I have the definition and brief description handy   in this link here.

[Linux Kernel Memory Barriers Documentation](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt)

However I was attempting to get a profound understanding of this concept. Your thoughts and inputs are highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Old answer: I believe "acquire semantics" is the more commonly used term for what the document is calling a  "data-dependency barrier".  See for example [this presentation](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Epingali/CS378/2012fa/lectures/consistency.pdf)  or the [C++11 memory_order_acquire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179938/c11-memory-order-acquire-and-memory-order-release-semantics).

Update: per comments, the [Linux description](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt) for Data Dependency Barriers sounds more like C++ "consume semantics".

Comment: @ Arch D. Robinson Thanks for the link very informative indeed!

Comment: Linux uses "acquire" operations but also a lot of "consume" for rarely changed data.

Comment: Actually it is "consume" semantics, instead of "acquire".

Answer (score 2):

Actually, at least in terms of C++11, this is more closely related to consume semantics. You can read more about it e.g. [here](http://preshing.com/20140709/the-purpose-of-memory_order_consume-in-cpp11/). In short, they provide weaker guarantees than acquire semantics, which makes them more efficient on certain platforms that support data dependency ordering.

Comment: Consume is also very natural in term of inherent dependency of f.ex. using a pointer: you need to know it first to dereference.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ terms, it is called [memory_order_consume](https://preshing.com/20140709/the-purpose-of-memory_order_consume-in-cpp11/). See this [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrNQKpOypqU) from [Paul Mckenney](https://www.linkedin.com/in/paulmckenney/).